# can use maxdop on online modifying column in mssql 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, datatypes, alter-table, maxdop

I want to change data type of a column of my table in SQL Server 2019.
My table has 50,000,000 row and it's very important.
I want to do this operation online and also handle maxdop to avoid CPU over usage.
I wrote this query but I got syntax error:

```
Alter table Customers
alter column FirstName char(16) not null
with (online = on, maxdop = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax-for-disk-based-tables), SQL Server 2019 `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` syntax does not support the `MAXDOP = x` option.

`MAXDOP = x` is only supported for single partition rebuilds and constraint operations.